# In angular2 whenever list change it selects first element, so how to avoid it?

Tags: html, jquery, angular, materialize

I am working on angular 9 and whenever list on which select it working is changed it selects first element by default. I am using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/select.html) for this. I tried  jquery and compareWith but no use.

```
<select id="valueSelect"
    data-[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
    [compareWith]="compareList"
    data-(change)="fetchMetaData();">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose value</option>
        <option data-*ngFor="let element1 of filterList"
            data-[ngValue]="bu.businessunitCode">{{element1.value}}</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select value</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

may i show fetchMetaData() function ?

replace `[ngValue]` to `[value]` may be it will work fine !

```
    <select id="valueSelect" 
             [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
             [compareWith]="compareList"
             (change)="fetchMetaData();">
         <option selected disabled>Choose value</option>
         <option *ngFor="let data of fadeIn" [value]="data">{{data}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: fetchMetadata add the value to list this is the only method which manipulate filterList

Comment: Replace [ngValue] to [value] may be it will work fine !